# How to submit a string arg to subprocess.run(arg, shell=True) when arg already contains " " and ' ' quotes?

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I have the following command that I need to issue using python 3.6  `subprocess.run()` function:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['apple@gmail.com', 'orange@yahoo.com']"
```

Because the `@` symbol is found in the list elements of this command, the run() function's `shell` kwarg must be set to True, i.e. `subprocess.run(arg, shell=True)`. Consequently, the syntax's rule of this function requires the above command be submitted as a string, i.e.

```
arg = "gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['apple@gmail.com', 'orange@yahoo.com']" "
```

Here lies my dilemma. The string quotes " " of the entire command are conflicting with the string quotes " " in the original command. How to I overcome this issue?

Comment: You me `arg = "gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions \"['apple@gmail.com', 'orange@yahoo.com']\" "` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape `"` or `'` with `\`: `\"`, `\'`.

Example:

```py
>>> v = "'\"\'"
>>> [ord(i) for i in v]
[39, 34, 39]
```

So in your case:

```
arg = "gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions \"['apple@gmail.com', 'orange@yahoo.com']\" "
```